# Term for how the Landlord makes sure he's covered

Tags: single-word-requests

When a landlord rents a property, he can insure himself in one of two ways:

- Security Deposit - an item or amount of money that is in the possession of the landlord and can be used to cover damages or failure to pay rent
- Guarantor - a person or body that accepts the responsibility to pay if the tenant is not able

What word can be used to group these terms together?

I am trying to find a good name for a tab in which the user can define whether the Contract uses one (or both) of these methods.

So far I have **financial protection**. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can they be referred to as **securities**?

Comment: like indemnity?

Comment: @SteveLovell - im afraid "securities" has a different implication: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_(finance)

Comment: @peerless - good word, but seems to only reflect the "guarantor" option

Comment: That was my concern about **securities**. There is a more general sense in the dictionary, but it would be easy to create confusion by using it.

Comment: Some other options might be **bond**, **surety**, **indenture**. It probably doesn't help the the world of finance has co-opted all these words and given them technical meanings.

Answer (score 7):

These are both **sureties**:

> 1. security against loss or damage or for the fulfillment of an obligation, the payment of a debt, etc.; a pledge, guaranty, or bond.
> 2. a person who has made himself or herself responsible for another, as a sponsor, godparent, or bondsman. - [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/surety)

Comment: thanks! Do you have any familiarity with the professional world and if this is commonly used?

Comment: No, I looked up *assurances* for you.